# Why am I receiving the “no longer accepting questions from this account” error?

Tags: support, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

I am accessing from my workplace and 2 of my questions got downvoted and only one get closed.

I would like to know the reason why I am banned?

Comment: Have you many deleted questions? Or do you share an IP address?

Comment: Oh please, surely you know the words "why", "question" and others... If this is illustrative of the quality of your questions, I might have an idea of what the problem is.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I access from my workplace...yeah it may be shared.My first Qn in SO is the deleted one with 1 downvote..And the second one is having 5 downvotes 2 updownvotes :(

Comment: @LithuThiruvathira Qn <-- wrong! Question <-- right!

Answer (score 8):

You should work on writing clear and comprehensible posts.

This is an excellent example of why your posts would receive negative attention: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/147624/revisions

This as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12444688/1

When you are abbreviating words with less than 4 characters on a constant basis, you should not expect anyone to take the time to answer your questions, nor should you expect for a site to want more of your questions.

Comment: made an edit on this question..right?What about the remaining i asked?

Comment: Those have all been [addressed previously](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes), @lithu. If you want to see the ban lifted, you'd do well to heed this advice.

Comment: A question is just that: A question. Your extra ranting and run-on rambling doesn't add anything to your main question.

Comment: You could start by spending time writing more intelligible comments as an example.

Comment: @GEOCHET :Hmm Ok

Comment: @Shog9 : Oov,didn't see that ..Thanks , will try :)

Comment: Why would you be asking more than one question in a single question post anyway?